# Extracting all links from webpage

Tags: python

I want to write a function that takes a web page URL, downloads the web page and returns a list of the URLs in that page.(with using urllib module)
any help would be appreciated

Comment: what do you have so far? what specific problem do you have?

Comment: We are not going to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
import sys
import urllib2
import lxml.html

try:
    url = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print "Specify a url to scrape"
    sys.exit(1)

if not url.startswith("http://"):
    print "Please include the http:// at the beginning of the url"
    sys.exit(1)

html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
etree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

for href in etree.xpath("//a/@href"):
    print href
```

---

```
C:\Programming>getlinks.py http://example.com
/
/domains/
/numbers/
/protocols/
/about/
/go/rfc2606
/about/
/about/presentations/
/about/performance/
/reports/
/domains/
/domains/root/
/domains/int/
/domains/arpa/
/domains/idn-tables/
/protocols/
/numbers/
/abuse/
http://www.icann.org/
mailto:iana@iana.org?subject=General%20website%20feedback
```

Comment: +1 for lxml its meant for this.

Comment: I've edited the script to download the page in a separate step using urllib2.